# 204 forbidden on azure storage

Tags: azure

The following request succceses:

```
HEAD https://ascendxyzweutest.blob.core.windows.net/b89e6c6cdde0421996a7ba47fcb57184-workset?restype=container HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WA-Storage/4.3.0 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.0; Win32NT 6.2.9200.0)
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
x-ms-client-request-id: b566c59d-b8ac-4b7e-9cfc-820337971cc9
x-ms-date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 00:59:17 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey ascendxyzweutest:+KdHX5Bewm5uP4lPHUtEcCv79tC3dQK28evyg1trOlw=
Host: ascendxyzweutest.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 The specified container does not exist.
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 2fa4a112-0001-0010-7b56-b4eb01000000
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
Date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 00:59:23 GMT
```

The above example is from teh .net Storage Library

Then I am with a WebRequest trying to do the same.

```
HEAD https://ascendxyzweutest.blob.core.windows.net/ccf2a083affa4e6c8d489fe1b2f0d32a-workset?restype=container HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
x-ms-client-request-id: 92afdcaf-5afe-4f6a-914e-4850a4f0bd1d
x-ms-date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 01:01:56 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey ascendxyzweutest:LRoIdLp0m4nR0XhRlcTT7gyyi6zYJhGg3fHmXKemPVc=
Host: ascendxyzweutest.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 61b7318c-0001-001c-6cc4-b6edcd000000
Date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 01:02:22 GMT
```

Every other post on this suggests that its the x-ms-date field that is off by more than 15min. I executed these two from teh same machine with 5min seperation and this is also what is seen in the request headers. So i dont believe that the time is off.

I am signing the request with the stuff form Azure Storage SDK.

```
public Task SignRequestAsync(HttpWebRequest request, string tenantid, string container)
        {
            var a = new SharedKeyAuthenticationHandler(SharedKeyCanonicalizer.Instance, account.Credentials, account.Credentials.AccountName);
            a.SignRequest(request,null);
            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }
```

Any pointers on what can have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav Mantri assisted me on this and found the issue. The issue was due to some headers being set that got used when calculating the signature, but these headers was omitted when doing the reqest. Content-Length being set to 0 ect.

> So the problem is with your “HEAD” request when you check if the container exists. Basically when calculating signature, you’re passing “Content-Length” (even though it’s value is 0) however it is not passed in as request headers. Thus your signature mismatches and you get 403 error. If I comment out the code where you set the “ContentLength” property of the request, your “HEAD” request succeeds (but then your PUT request would fail).